# FCRSystemMetadata - Sometimes Prevents IOS App Suspending

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

FCRSystemMetadata has lots of CPU activity every 5 seconds which is preventing our from sleeping while in background.

I can't figure out the source of this, I thought it was Firebase Crash Reporter, but I commented out that code and import statement and I still see this issue. Looks like related to some sort of memory statistics or something like that.

Funny thing is that it doesn't happen all the time, somethings I send the app to background and the app sleeps/suspends as it should, but other times I'll see this CPU activity every 5 seconds.

I made a video of the issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/addpmbl4if40iv8/pyng%20cpu%3Anetwork%20issue.mov?dl=0

Any clues is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to a video 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable **code** example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[this meta link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but not sure how I would add the code to this as it is a issue running the whole app and not just a portion of it.